# How to bypass filter if a tag is included?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash instance processing incoming requests on port 5044.
I have then filebeat and metricbeat sending data.

Problem is that currently logstash is configured to accept only filebeat files due to a filter:

```
input {
beats {
  port => "5044"
}
}
filter {
grok {
    match => {...

}
output { ...
```

and metricbeat data is, of course, discarded.
Would it be possible to include metricbeat data by defining an exception to that filter? My idea would to be add a tag to metricbeat so to be recognized....is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by the beat type using the field `@metadata.beat` in a conditional.

It would be something like this:

```
filter {
    if [@metadata][beat] == "filebeat" {
        filters for filebeat
    }
    if [@metadata][beat] == "metricbeat" {
        filters for metricbeat
    }
}
```

You can also use the same conditional in the `output` block if you want to store the data from each beats in a different index.